# How to avoid that elements in JavaDoc {@link } are found when I search for references (in Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Writing f.ex. `{@link MyClass#myMethod()}` in a JavaDoc comment is really great, especially for the clickable link I get in the tooltip, but if I go to `MyClass` and I right-click `myMethod()` and select the *Reference* menu item to find all the calls to `myMethod()`, in the search results I also get all the references to that method made from JavaDoc comments.

I would highly prefer to only get the references made from actual code, without the references made from `{@link` tags in JavaDoc comments. Is there a way ?

ADDED: Certainly an advantage of those references inside JavaDoc being considered as "actual" code is that they will be included in refactoring, so when I rename the method those references in JavaDoc will be renamed too, which is great, so the best thing would be if there was a way to have them found by refactoring but not by just searching...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a filter within the search result view to exclude matches found in Javadoc.

Just click on the triangle dropdown in the upper right corner and select "In Javadoc" or customize via the "filters..." settings.

Comment: Wonderful, and this also solves the extra wish I just added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use **Open in Call Hierarchy** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) for that kind of search. I find that as a better choice anyway, since it lets me easily explore the full call stack for the method in question, not just the immediate callers.

Comment: This is also clever, however I prefer to handle the results in the Search view as it provides more facilities. Also, most of the times I'm just interested in just the immediate callers.